# Cannot boot up FreeNAS

Tags: nas, freenas

I've been using a FreeNAS server for the past 6 months and recently, something happened and it's not able to boot up completely now. After attaching a monitor to the server, I've found multiple logs saying "Periph destroyed" pertaining to almost all my disk devices. Not trying to panic but I really don't know what the messages mean. And I can't even drop to the shell to investigate anything so the logs are all I have.

I'm using FreeNAS 9.3. My server is a typical Intel PC server. I can't remember specifics about the server build but if anyone thinks it's pertinent information I can dig out my receipts.

Appreciate any pointers towards what may the problem be and how to solve it.

[image: Screenshot of error in FreeNAS]

[image: Screenshot of error in FreeNAS]

[image: Screenshot of error in FreeNAS]

[image: Screenshot of error in FreeNAS]

Comment: Check this freenas [post](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/asrock-c2550d4i-drive-detaching.29001/). It just sucks when this happens and you don't know where to start

Comment: Found that it was due to a faulty connection from the motherboard to the hard disks. Took it back to the shop who fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found that it was due to a faulty connection from the motherboard to the hard disks. Took it back to the shop who fixed it for me. Thanks!